# How to extract text from very large XML files in Python without interrupting tags while parsing incrementally?

Tags: python, xml, large-files

EDIT: After I tried the first answer, I still get text broken at interrupting tags (just as before). For reference, here is the code:

```
    for event, element in ET.iterparse(path):
        if element.tag == "idsText":
            # move sentences from stack
            if sents:
                cat_texts.extend(sents)
                visited[current_doc] = visited.get(current_doc, 0) + 1
                # another function call
                annotate(cat_texts, filename, current_doc, visited[current_doc])
                # reset cat_texts
                cat_texts = []
            # set new current document's name
            current_doc = element.get("n")
            sents = []
        # new sentence starts
        elif element.tag == "s" and type(element.text) == str:
            if element.text.strip():
                sentence = ' '.join(element.itertext())
                new_sent.extend(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence, language='german'))
                sents.append(new_sent)
                new_sent = []

        element.clear()
```

I have some very large xml files (> 6 GB) and want to extract text from them. The problem is that the text is interrupted by other tags. Here is a dummy file to get you an idea:

```
<doc>
    <s> Here you can see a <ref target="SOME_URL" targOrder="u">reference</ref> in the text. </s>
</doc>
```

I want to get this:

```
Here you can see a reference in the text.
```

I use this code (though I leave out the specifics here):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
for event, element in ET.iterparse(path):
    if element.tag == "doc":
        # do something here            
    
    elif element.tag == "s" and type(element.text) == str:
        if element.text.strip():
            # again do something here

    element.clear()
```

This code applied to the dummy file would produce this:

```
Here you can see a
```

I know that itertext() would produce the output I want:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
myxml = '<doc><s> Here you can see a <ref target="SOME_URL" targOrder="u">reference</ref> in the text. </s></doc>'
tree = ET.fromstring(myxml)
print(''.join(tree.itertext()))
```

Output:

```
Here you can see a reference in the text.
```

But I can't think of a way to combine this with iterparse() (or any other incremental parsing method). Because I can't parse the xml into a tree all at once due to its size. And doing it incrementally means that itertext() won't work because the following tag (<ref in this case) isn't parsed yet when the element with the tag  is parsed.

Is there a way to get all the text inside an element and stripping the tags when parsing incrementally?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `itertext` method to recursively iterate over all the text content contained in an element. If we rewrite your code like this:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
for event, element in ET.iterparse('data.xml'):
        if element.tag == 's':
            print(' '.join(element.itertext()))
```

Then given your sample input we get the following output:

```
 Here you can see a  reference  in the text.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me :( It always breaks the sentence at interrupting tags.

Comment: This works fine for me with your sample data (using Python 3.11). If you're using different input data, please update your question with an example that produces the same behavior. If you're using a different version of Python, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see also the tag’s:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import io
from html.parser import HTMLParser

xml="""<doc>
    <s> Here you can see a <ref target="SOME_URL" targOrder="u">reference</ref> in the text. </s>
</doc>"""

infile = io.StringIO(xml)

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if len(attrs) != 0:
            print("Encountered a start tag:", tag, attrs)
        else:
            print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)
            
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()

for event, element in ET.iterparse(infile, events=("end",)):
    if event == "end" and element.tag == 's':
        print(ET.tostring(element).decode("utf-8"))
        print(parser.feed(ET.tostring(element).decode("utf-8")))
```

Output:

```
<s> Here you can see a <ref target="SOME_URL" targOrder="u">reference</ref> in the text. </s>

Encountered a start tag: s
Encountered some data  :  Here you can see a 
Encountered a start tag: ref [('target', 'SOME_URL'), ('targorder', 'u')]
Encountered some data  : reference
Encountered an end tag : ref
Encountered some data  :  in the text. 
Encountered an end tag : s
Encountered some data  : None
```